# How does Laravel queue work and what if php artisan queue:listen stops

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have installed beanstaled and its working fine with laravel. The point where I am puzzled is that we have to do

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

to start listening queue. Right now, I am using it on amazone ec2 instance remotely through putty. but what is i close terminal? Will the jobs created through the code will work? Is it manually calling `php artisan queue:listen` or `php artisan queue:work` all time. Which does not seems fair.

If once `php artisan queue:listen` done, will it keep on running even if we close terminal?

Actually I dont know.

Answer (score 11):

you need to install supervisor also. Here is a tutorial on using beanstalkd with laravel:

http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4

Here are details on supervisor also:

http://supervisord.org/installing.html

I personally use a redis instance and run my queue with supervisor from there.
I find its a bit more memory effective then beanstalkd personally but each to there own.

Supervisor will execute the queue:listen command from artisan and this will run a job, if you have multiple supervisor processes then you can run multiple in line items.
depending on what you are doing i would almost look into python and multithereading also as i have used this for a few things i used to use a queue for and it has provided even better results.

example config file for supervisor:

```
[program:myqueue]
command=php artisan queue:listen --env=your_environment
directory=/path/to/laravel
stdout_logfile=/path/to/laravel/app/storage/logs/myqueue_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Comment: but what about `php artisan queue:listen`, the main question was that

Comment: This does answer the question, although indirectly. `php artisan queue:listen` will run for a while (I can't remember the time out) and then exit. This is a limitation of PHP. Once it stops, no more jobs will be executed. To get around this, install `supervisor` as the answer suggests - `supervisor` will watch the `queue:listen` process and will restart it when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of Laravel's **Task Scheduler** i.e add the `php artisan queue:listen` command to the scheduler and sets its frequency to whatever you wants.

So that will make sure to call queue listen process automatically.

Hope it will make sense.

Comment: Won't this spawn a new process every time the scheduler runs?