# How to deploy laravel project on windows server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I am new to laravel and still learning.

At first, I develop a laravel project on my own computer. As i know, when run php artisan serve command and open XAMPP, then the laravel project will open on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ .

I want to deploy the project on window server. Do i need to run `php artisan serve` on server continuously, so that the laravel project can be running on server side and accessible to public?

Any help will be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You should install something like apache or nginx to host it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do that with git. Push your project on git & pull it on your windows server.

Beside you can do a manual things like zip your project upload to your server & then unzip them.Create a database on the server.
After that edit your `.env` file and change the details of your database

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your database name you just created on the server
DB_USERNAME=yourdatabase username...............
DB_PASSWORD=your database password .............
```

After that check if there is .htaccess file or not if not then create one & paste the below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Fahim Ahmed. I got the idea how it works.

Comment: @Malca you are welcome . Still if you have any issue uploading you can ask me.

Comment: How about php artisan queue:work ?. I run the command during development, to send email to user. I'm using smtp.gmail.com for MAIL_HOST during development.

Comment: you can check out the official documentation for the queue:work https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues  & also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601634/how-does-laravel-queue-work-and-what-if-php-artisan-queuelisten-stops

Comment: Thanks @Fahim Ahmed, i will read it and tried which solution suit with my project.